# Relation between BDT volatility and Hull-White one factor Volatility

Tags: interest-rates, hullwhite, bdt

Is there any mathematical relationship between the volatility of spot rates calibrated from Lognormal model and the volatility of spot rates calibrated from HW one factor model?